# How to interpet wireshark signal strength

Tags: geolocation, wireless, wifi

I use Google for hours but I do not find a satisfying answer how to interpret the captured signal strength, given by the radiotap header. For instance Wireshark shows me a SSI Signal of -52 dBm and I want to convert it to a linear representation/unit. For me, a sensible unit would be the signal power at the antenna in Watt over mW. Is it possible to convert this -52 dBm to mW?

Some background information: I implement a WLAN-based localisation and want to estimate the position of APs by combining some reference points and the measured signal strength. With the help of triangulation, this should produce a rough map of the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained quite well on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm), you can convert from x dBm to P Watts by applying:

```
P = 10**((x-30)/10)
```

So in your case, -52 dBm = 6.3 nW, which seems about right.

Comment: Thanks, this was the first page I found and I got the same value you calculated and it seemed too small. Somehow I managed to overlook the table below the formulas. There I found an entry for "Typical maximum received signal power" with a strength of -10 dBm, and now I trust my own calculations.